# Django Form so many fields

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, modelform

I have a Django page using bootstrap and crispy forms that present a form. but the form is growing so much now that I probably have around 50 fields :( which are all within 1 massive HTML page. I'm pretty sure this is the wrong way to do it.

Is it possible to split the forms into say 5 pages, but still have a submit button to post all of the fields to the database?

For now, what I have done is to create tabs for each section of the giant form so it's easy than scrolling.

I'm thinking it's probably better to create different views for each section and then link the data somehow back using an IndexKey or something?

But i have no idea how i would configure the button to capture all the fields.

I know this is a rubbish question, but I don't really know what to search for?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to divide the form in bootstrap tabs like
Personal information --> form fields
Additional information --> form fields

Comment: Thats what i have done, i basically have 5 tabs. but all the html is all in 1 page. This might be fine, im just checking that this is ok to do, or should i seperate the html into 5 pages as rasta says

Comment: You can split it up for programmer-sanity purposes using `{% include %}`,  or `{% block xxx %}` and inheritance `{% extends yyy %}`. One file per bootstrap tab and the bootstrap overall design in the base template?

Comment: There's also the Django Form Wizard if you start needing to obtain information in sub-forms based on previous answers. It's a bit of a sledgehammer for simply breaking a large form into multiple "tabs" or other divisions. https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you break the data input down into as many questions as you think is appropriate for each page? If you have 50 inputs, you could do 10 over 5 pages.

After submitting Page 1, return the POST data to Page 2 and store the data in hidden input fields. Repeat the process until Page 5 when you can POST all 50 to the server and insert the data into your Database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, would this mean that i would have 40 hidden fields on the 5 page and 10 unhidden?  Suppose that would look nicer from a UX point of view? 
How do i return the Post data to page 2 and so on?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was suggesting. You could have the user click the next page button, which would call a function that would post the data from the first page to the server via an AJAX call. You could then return the data to page 2 as a JSON object and store in hidden input fields.

Comment: Sounds good, but i've not got the skills to do that.